# Testing strategy on Relay + React

Tags: reactjs, tdd, graphql, relayjs

I am experimenting with React + Relay + Graphql these days. Unfortunately, I cannot find any easy and convenient way to test React component wrapped by Relay Container.

Basically, I would like to achieve these goals along TDD,

1. Render a container and test its content,
2. Change variables and test its changes on content.

Compared with React + Flux, React + Relay is more like black box, or, declarative.

I can see people mock Relay.createContainer to bypass Relay and merely test React Component. It leaves the Relay part uncovered and there is no way to *drive* this part by testing.
https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/161

Also, I read through test cases of Relay and its really tedious to render a mock container.
[https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/tools/**mocks**/RelayTestUtils.js](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/tools/__mocks__/RelayTestUtils.js)

I will be really grateful if you can share you solution.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the best idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327428/integration-testing-of-relay-containers-with-jest-against-a-working-graphql-back

Answer (score 12):

I've been trying to test Relay containers like I would components in a Flux application. Specifically, I want to make sure that they render the correct content for a given state and props and that they call methods to change data in appropriate places; in Flux this is a call to an action creator, in Relay this is a call to `Relay.Store.update` or `this.props.relay.setVariables`.

My first attempt was to build a `RelayTestUtil` object with a `renderContainerIntoDocument` method. I based it heavily on [https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/tools/**mocks**/RelayTestUtils.js](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/tools/__mocks__/RelayTestUtils.js), [https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/legacy/store/**mocks**/GraphQLStoreQueryResolver.js](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/legacy/store/__mocks__/GraphQLStoreQueryResolver.js), and the Relay Container tests. This used very minimal mocking and was great for testing container rendering but was completely useless for testing data changes. Trying to spy on calls to `Relay.Store.update` and `this.props.relay.setVariables`, or to mock data changes, became more trouble than it was worth.

I settled on adding `__mocks__\react-relay.js` to completely mock Relay and using simpler version of `RelayTestUtils.renderContainerIntoDocument` to inject Relay properties into a container. I'm not entirely satisfied with this solution, but it seems to work for now.

`__mocks__\react-relay.js`:

```js
var Relay = require.requireActual('react-relay');
var React = require('react');

module.exports = {
  QL: Relay.QL,
  Mutation: Relay.Mutation,
  Route: Relay.Route,
  Store: {
    update: jest.genMockFn()
  },
  createContainer: (component, containerSpec) => {
    const fragments = containerSpec.fragments || {};

    // mock the static container methods
    Object.assign(component, { getFragment: (fragmentName) => fragments[fragmentName] });

    return component;
  }
};
```

`RelayTestUtils.js`:

```js
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


const RelayTestUtils = {
  renderContainerIntoDocument(containerElement, relayOptions) {
    relayOptions = relayOptions || {};

    const relaySpec = {
      forceFetch: jest.genMockFn(),
      getPendingTransactions: jest.genMockFn().mockImplementation(() => relayOptions.pendingTransactions),
      hasOptimisticUpdate: jest.genMockFn().mockImplementation(() => relayOptions.hasOptimisticUpdate),
      route: relayOptions.route || { name: 'MockRoute', path: '/mock' },
      setVariables: jest.genMockFn(),
      variables: relayOptions.variables || {}
    };

    return ReactDOM.render(
      React.cloneElement(containerElement, { relay: relaySpec }),
      document.createElement('div')
    );
  }
};

export default RelayTestUtils;
```

Tests look something like this, where `fragmentData` matches the shape of the GraphQL response:

```js
it('changes items', () => {
  const myContainer = RelayTestUtils.renderContainerIntoDocument(
    <MyContainer { ...fragmentData }/>, 
    { variables: { itemId: 'asdf' } }
  );
  myContainer.changeItem();
  expect(myContainer.props.relay.setVariables).toBeCalled();
});
```

Comment: Would it not also be possible to just 'mock' out the network layer? So similar to pretender (https://github.com/pretenderjs/pretender) relay could actually send off the query but then instead of talking to a server it just gets back mock data.

Comment: @agrauch, could u provide a repo of example?

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote a blog post of how to test Relay using Jest against a working GraphQL backend: https://medium.com/entria/relay-integration-test-with-jest-71236fb36d44#.an74bdopy

This repo https://github.com/sibelius/relay-integration-test contains examples of testing react web and react native using Relay